# How do I use a function with parameters in optim in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to use the optim function in R - I have no problems with this:

```
funk=function(param){
  x=c(1,2,3,4,5)
  z=c(3,4,2,2,1)
  y=c(30,40,22,33,40)
  a=rep(param[1],5)
  b=param[2]
  d=param[3]
  fit=sum((y-(a+b*x+z*d))^2)
  return(fit)
}

optim(par=c(1,1,1),fn=funk)
```

#

But as soon as I don't want to hard-code my data (x,y,z) into the function I have problems. How do I optimize a function in optim when the function input is more than just the parameters to be optimized? Ideally I would pass on value of xx, zz, yy then optimize, then move to differnt values of xx, zz, yy and optimize that case next.

```
xx=c(1,2,3,4,5)
zz=c(3,4,2,2,1)
yy=c(30,40,22,33,40)

funk=function(param,x,y,z){
  a=rep(param[1],5)
  b=param[2]
  d=param[3]
  fit=sum((y-(a+b*x+z*d))^2)
  return(fit)
}

optim(par=c(1,1,1),fn=funk(param=c(0,0,0),x=xx,y=yy,z=zz))
```

Error in (function (par)  : could not find function "fn"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In `optim`, `...` is used to pass arguments to `fn`:

```
xx=c(1,2,3,4,5)
zz=c(3,4,2,2,1)
yy=c(30,40,22,33,40)

funk=function(param,x,y,z){
  a=rep(param[1],5)
  b=param[2]
  d=param[3]
  fit=sum((y-(a+b*x+z*d))^2)
  return(fit)
}

optim(par=c(1,1,1), fn=funk, x=xx, y=yy, z=zz) 
$par
[1] -1.863076  5.722988  7.372296

$value
[1] 124.075

$counts
function gradient 
     180       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Comment: Is this the same for optimx?

Comment: Please read the help file `?optimx`. It is clearly written `...    For optimx further arguments to be passed to fn and gr; otherwise, further arguments are not used.`

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68280857/r-x-probs-outside-0-1 thanks!