# R: x 'probs' outside [0,1]

Tags: r, function, optimization, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am using the R programming language.

I am trying to follow the instructions from the "optimization" package in R (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optimization/optimization.pdf)  and use functions from this package on a specific function.

For this example, I first generate some random data:

```
#load libraries
library(dplyr)


# create some data for this example
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)
c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)
```

From here, I define the function that I want to optimize ("fitness"). This function takes 7 inputs  and calculates a "total" mean (a single scalar value). The inputs required for this function are:

- "random_1" (between 80 and 120)
- "random_2" (between "random_1" and 120)
- "random_3" (between 85 and 120)
- "random_4" (between random_2 and 120)
- "split_1" (between 0 and 1)
- "split_2" (between 0 and 1)
- "split_3" (between 0 and 1 )

The function to optimize is defined as follows:

```
library(optimization)

fitness <- function(x) {
  #bin data according to random criteria
  train_data <- train_data %>% 
                 mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= x[1] & b1 <= x[3], "a", 
                               ifelse(a1 <= x[2] & b1 <= x[4], "b", "c")))

 train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
    
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
   
    
    #calculate  quantile ("quant") for each bin
    
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = x[5])))
    
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = x[6])))
    
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = x[7])))
    
    
    
    
    #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger tha the value of "c1"
    table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$c1,1,0)
    table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$c1,1,0)
    table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$c1,1,0)
    
    #group all tables
    
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
# calculate the total mean : this is what needs to be optimized
    mean = mean(final_table$diff)
    
    
}
```

From here, I am trying to run the following optimization function:

```
Output <- optim_nm(fitness, k = 7, trace = TRUE)

plot(output)
 plot(Output, 'contour')
```

But these return the following errors:

```
 Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `quant`.
i `quant = quantile(c1, prob = x[6])`.
x 'probs' outside [0,1]
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. 

Error in plot(Output) : object 'Output' not found
```

I think error is that the "split_1", "split_2" and "split_3" variables are being assigned values outside of 0 and 1 : since the function is using these variables are used to calculate percentiles (e.g. `quant = quantile(c1, prob = x[5]` ) , this will naturally result in an error?

I tried to use another optimization algorithm from this package where the ranges for these 7 inputs are explicitly defined, but this is also producing the same error :

```
ro_sa <- optim_sa(fun = fitness,
start = c(runif(7, min = -1, max = 1)),
lower = c(80,80,80,80,0,0,0),
upper = c(120,120,120,120,1,1,1),
trace = TRUE,
control = list(t0 = 100,
nlimit = 550,
t_min = 0.1,
dyn_rf = FALSE,
rf = 1,
r = 0.7
)
)

 Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `quant`.
i `quant = quantile(c1, prob = x[6])`.
x 'probs' outside [0,1]
```

This also doesn't work if you provide an initial starting point:

```
optim_nm(fitness, start = c(80,80,80,80,0.5,0.6,0.7))

 Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `quant`.
i `quant = quantile(c1, prob = x[5])`.
x 'probs' outside [0,1]
i The error occurred in group 1: cat = a.
```

**Question:** Can someone please show me how to fix this, so that I can run the optimization functions?

```
#desired functions to run:

Output <- optim_nm(fitness, k = 7, trace = TRUE)

plot(output)
 plot(Output, 'contour')

ro_sa <- optim_sa(fun = fitness,
start = c(runif(7, min = -1, max = 1)),
lower = c(80,80,80,80,0,0,0),
upper = c(120,120,120,120,1,1,1),
trace = TRUE,
control = list(t0 = 100,
nlimit = 550,
t_min = 0.1,
dyn_rf = FALSE,
rf = 1,
r = 0.7
)
)

optim_nm(fitness, start = c(80,80,80,80,0.5,0.6,0.7))
```

Thanks

Comment: In your fitness function you could just set limits along the lines of `x[5] <- min(max(x[5], 0), 1)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am still new to manipulating functions, if you have time, can you please show me what you mean? Thank you so much!

Comment: Instead of optimizing probability `p` you could optimize `logit(p) = log(p/(1-p))`, which takes values ranging from -infinity to infinity. Then the bounds don't matter. Given a value `l` of the logit you can get back the probability with `p <- 1/(1+exp(-l))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` values generated are random and they can be positive or negative. `probs` argument of `quantile` needs to have values between 0 and 1. One way would be to take the absolute value of `x[5:7]` and turn them to ratio using `prop.table`.

```
x[5:7] <- prop.table(abs(x[5:7]))
```

Complete function -

```
library(optimization)

fitness <- function(x) {
  #bin data according to random criteria
  train_data <- train_data %>% 
    mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= x[1] & b1 <= x[3], "a", 
                        ifelse(a1 <= x[2] & b1 <= x[4], "b", "c")))
  
  train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
  
  #new splits
  a_table = train_data %>%
    filter(cat == "a") %>%
    select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
  
  b_table = train_data %>%
    filter(cat == "b") %>%
    select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
  
  c_table = train_data %>%
    filter(cat == "c") %>%
    select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
  
  
  x[5:7] <- prop.table(abs(x[5:7]))
  
  #calculate  quantile ("quant") for each bin
  
  table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                         mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = x[5])))
  
  table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                         mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = x[6])))
  
  table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                         mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = x[7])))
  
  
  #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger tha the value of "c1"
  table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$c1,1,0)
  table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$c1,1,0)
  table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$c1,1,0)
  
  #group all tables
  
  final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
  # calculate the total mean : this is what needs to be optimized
  mean = mean(final_table$diff) 
}
```

You can apply and plot this function -

```
Output <- optim_nm(fitness, k = 7, trace = TRUE)
plot(Output)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Is it possible to "plot contours" for two of the variables (e.g. [1] and [2])?

Comment: e.g.  plot(Output[1], Output[2], 'contour')

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question if you have some time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68324822/correctly-specifying-logical-conditions-in-r thank you